# Browse in low-bandwidth mode

Tags: browser, bandwidth

I am using internet in limited bandwidth. To keep bandwidth consuming low, I have disabled loading images, used adblock in firefox. I can't use opera turbo mode, because some sites are broken in opera. But is there any way, I can reduce bandwidth usage further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of Flash Player altogether. I'm not sure what OS you use, but say you wanted to do this with Safari in OS X, you would navigate to:

`/Library/Internet Plug-ins/`

Then you would simply move flashplayer.xpt, Flash Player.plugin, NP-PPC-Dir-Shockwave, out of that directory. You can always move them back later. Now there's no Flash to chew up bandwidth, or rather if it wanted to it couldn't.

There are similar techniques for other OSes and browsers. The advantage to the method outlined above is that it's easily reversible.

[NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) is another good option for avoiding useless bandwidth eaters in Firefox.